# ORA-01031: insufficient privileges

Tags: sql, oracle, ddl

I've got this error and I don't know what is it about. The query:

```
CREATE VIEW UNPAID AS SELECT * FROM fullday
UNION
SELECT * FROM halfday
MINUS
SELECT class_no, child_no FROM payment;
```

Comment: Maybe you don't have privileges to create Views?

Comment: @EvertonAgner: not "maybe" - most definitely he doesn't

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name Actually, I was being ironic

Answer (score 3):

You should grant the user the `CREATE VIEW` privilege and `SELECT` privileges on all the tables making up the view.
Assuming the user you're using is `usr`, use one of the administrative users and perform:

```
GRANT CREATE VIEW TO usr;
GRANT SELECT ON fullday TO usr;
GRANT SELECT ON halfday TO usr;
GRANT SELECT ON payment TO usr;
```

Comment: usr is which want? the username to login oracle?

Comment: @KelvinYap The user you used to log into Oracle and attempted to create the view from

Comment: I cannot run the code.